# haxe/flash: Capture webcam to disc with node.js - possible?

Tags: node.js, flash, red5, haxe

I know I could resolve the problem easily with Red5 Media Server. I'm just curious, since I need a node server anyway and wondered if I can bypass Red5. Using the HTML5 camera api is not an option since I target up to four cameras at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see anything specific for Node.js to work with webcams. However, I saw [this solution](http://francisshanahan.com/index.php/2011/stream-a-webcam-using-javascript-nodejs-android-opera-mobile-web-sockets-and-html5/) online which uses JavaScript, NodeJs, HTML5 (canvas) and WebSockets mainly to achieve frames out of video streaming then it uses the websockets to transfer the image into HTML5 canvas using NodeJs as an intermediary server.

hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Mamdouh. Thanks for the answer. I came that far and a bit farther. I used the pure getImageData() Array and BinaryJS to avoid the base64 encoding in the frontend. But it's hard to get decent quality. I went back to flash: http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/updated-flv-encoder-alchem/ which is fast solves video and audio and in a good quality. After finishing the recording I send the flv to the server.

Comment: That would be legit too. However, even quality issues should be solvable by using the same approach but I haven't experienced such thing yet. 
anyways, thanks for accepting my answer. and if you posted a question about base64 encoding please post it here in the comment section so I can follow it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of   https://www.npmjs.com/package/camera-capture which supports portable easy to use API for node.js (server side) to capture camera video, audio and even desktop. Doesn't require any native libraries / dependencies and is easy to install - based on puppeteer. I'm already using it on desktop apps based on gtk, cairo, qt, and others and it's behaving acceptably fast although I keep looking for optimizations since the project it's pretty new. Feedback is most welcome.